# NSolve the following equation

Tags: equation-solving

I tried using `NSolve` for the below equation

```
NSolve[Log[((E^x)^(E^x))^(1/(E^x)^(E^x))] - x == \[PlusMinus]0.0005, x]
```

but it didn't work. Instead I received an error message: "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to `NSolve`". I tried running it on WolframAlpha and it gave me the answer that I needed, so I was wondering if I was doing it wrong?

Comment: It should be `Log[]` not `Log()`.

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately. My output became NSolve[-x + Log[((E^x)^E^x)^(E^x)^-E^x] == 0.0005, x] and didn't give me the answer that I needed. Thanks for the typo fix though.

Comment: What is \\[PlusMinus] defined to be? If you look up PlusMinus in the help system that is just a character without any defined meaning. As Corey shows, you can replace that with - and FindRoot can get you an answer or you can replace it with + and get a different answer.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the [docs of `PlusMinus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlusMinus.html) under *Details*: "`PlusMinus[x,y,…]` has no built-in meaning". So you'd have to search for a root in each case separately.

I'd use `FindRoot`. To guess starting values, plot the function

```
f[x_] := Log[((E^x)^(E^x))^(1/(E^x)^(E^x))] - x
```

first:

```
plot1 = Plot[f[x], {x, -10, 10}];
plot2 = Plot[f[x], {x, -0.1, 0.1}];
plot = GraphicsRow[{plot1, plot2}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Therefore:

```
FindRoot[f[x] == 0.0005, {x, -0.1}]
```

> {x -> -0.0805186}

```
FindRoot[f[x] == -0.0005, {x, 0.1}]
```

> {x -> 0.0784163}

The thing is that `NSolve` tries to find all roots - also the complex ones. `FindRoot` restricts itself to reals due to the starting value. Often specifying the domain is useful in such cases:

```
NSolve[f[x] == 0.0005, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -0.0805186}}

and similar for the other sign.

I often use also `FindInstance`, which works also in this case:

```
FindInstance[f[x] == 0.0005 && x < 0, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -0.0805186}}

Note the `x < 0` - without it doesn't work. Similarly for the other sign.

Finally, there's also `Reduce`:

```
Reduce[f[x] == 0.0005, x, Reals]
```

> x == -0.0805186

and similarly for the other sign (although with a warning).

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you so much for your help. I should have used the function FindRoot from the start.

Comment: Not really. There are many ways to solve this, like `FindRoot`, `NSolve`, `FindInstance`, ... . Often it's about some tweaking, like in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think PlusMinus is an overloaded operator!? (someone correct me if im wrong).

So we have to solve this for each sign of $\pm0.0005$ .
But we notice very soon, that 
`NSolve[Log[((E^x)^(E^x))^(1/(E^x)^(E^x))] - x == 0.0005, x]`
wont work.
But this can be done if we specify that Mathematica should only search in the real domain.

```
NSolve[Log[((E^x)^(E^x))^(1/(E^x)^(E^x))]-x==0.0005,x,Reals]
```

> {{x->-0.0805186}}

But with a little trick with the [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html) Function we can go make it work.

```
NSolve[Abs[Log[((E^x)^(E^x))^(1/(E^x)^(E^x))] - x] == 0.0005, x, Reals]
```

> {{x -> -0.0805186}, {x -> 0.0784163}}

But i would prefer to use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) :

```
FindRoot[(-1 + Exp[x - Exp[x]*x])*x == 0.0005, {x, 1}]
```

> {x -> -0.0805186}

If we pack this nicely in a function with the $\pm\epsilon$ as a parameter we can do this pretty neatly (while I also simplified your equation):

```
FindEpsilonInterval[\[Epsilon]_?NumericQ] := x /. (FindRoot[(-1 + Exp[x - Exp[x]*x])* x == #*\[Epsilon], {x, -#*1}] & /@ {1, -1})
FindEpsilonInterval[0.0005]
```

> {-0.0805186, 0.0784163}

The function also visualize very well:

```
Plot[FindEpsilonInterval[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you so much for your help. I should have used the function FindRoot from the start.